# bypass a url in shiro security

Tags: java, spring-mvc, shiro

I am using shiro security framework in my webapp for security. and shiro is working properly but i want url = "/pricing/noAuth/*" type of urls not to be authorized or bypass shiro simply but other urls "/pricing/**" to pass through.

My shiro settings :

```
            [main]
            authc.successUrl = /dashboard
            authc.failureKeyAttribute = shiroLoginFailure

            [roles]
            ROLE_ADMIN = *

            [urls]
            /static/** = anon
            /pricing/noAuth/whrToBuy/** = anon
            /** = authc
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this. In shiro the filter scans in order so this should work

```
[main]
            authc.successUrl = /dashboard
            authc.failureKeyAttribute = shiroLoginFailure

            [roles]
            ROLE_ADMIN = *

            [urls]
            /static/** = anon
            /pricing/noAuth/** = anon
            /pricing/** = authc
            /** = authc
```

Comment: thanks for help...but this is not working  /pricing/noAuth/** is still redirecting to login page.. any more suggestion

Comment: Will try to create a scenario with same config. I cant find why it will not work as you can see /static/** is anonymous and /** is protected so it should work same for second use case. Only order of urls matters the first match will decide what it is designated for.